# Patching a generator in mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to create a mock version of a generator method for my unit tests. Setting the return value is easy:

```
    patcher = unittest.mock.patch.multiple("__main__.MyClass",
        method_one=DEFAULT,
        ...
    )
    patcher.start()
    MyClass.method_one.return_value = my_mock_gen(some_params)
```

However this will only work once and has to be reset every time:

```
    for value in my_obj.method_one(some_params):
        # do stuff with value

    my_obj.method_one.reset_mock() # doesn't work with `yield from` as well
```

Plus I am not able to generate mock values based on `some_params`. Is there a preferred way of handling this scenario that I am missing?

Comment: regarding reset issue, instead of `method_one=DEFAULT`, how about change to `method_one=mock.Mock(return_value='mocked foo!'),` or define `return_value` before `patcher.start()`?

Comment: The problem is that a new iterator should be generated on the go instead of reusing the one set via `return_value=...`. I don’t think your suggestion will change anything, but I will accept your answer if you can provide a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run a function when a mock is called, that's [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect), not `return_value`:

```
MyClass.method_one.side_effect = my_mock_gen
```

Comment: `side_effect` is way better and have more control over data, Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I thought `side_effect` merely creates side effects and not affect the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert `generator` to `list` for testing. It works, but it might be bad.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import mock
    import unittest


    class FooBar(object):

        def method_one(self, a, b):
            for i in range(a, b):
                yield i * i

        def bar(self):
            return 'bar'


    def mock_generator(a, b):
        for i in range(a, b):
            yield (i + 1) * i


    class TestFooBar(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_method_one(self):
            # set default to a list
            mock_method_one = mock.Mock(return_value=['aaa', 'ccc'])
            # this is how I access the class
            patcher = mock.patch.multiple(
                "python_tools.tests.patch_multiple.FooBar",
                method_one=mock_method_one,
                bar=mock.Mock(return_value='bar')
            )

            patcher.start()
            # method_one return generator only supposed to be read once
            # convert generator to list for testing, crazy?! not sure
            # [6, 12] after converting to list
            mock_method_one.return_value = list(mock_generator(2, 4))
            fb = FooBar()

            # no change
            self.assertEqual(fb.method_one(200, 500), [6, 12])

            # no change
            for item in fb.method_one(2, 5):
                self.assertTrue(item, [6, 12])

            # no change
            self.assertEqual(fb.method_one(1, 6), [6, 12])

            patcher.stop()
```

Comment: Apologies, but I should have mentioned that `method_one` in my tests uses `yield` (since it is a generator method) which does not return a simple list.